# send_email() takes 1 positional argument but 3 were given - Django Python

Tags: django, python-3.x, pycharm

I am trying to send a test email from my Django python project and following the django docs for that. When the below function is executed I get an error (image attached). What I am doing wrong?

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/email/

```
from django.core.mail import send_mail, BadHeaderError
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect

    def send_email(request):
        subject = request.POST.get('subject', 'Test')
        message = request.POST.get('message', 'Test Message')
        from_email = request.POST.get('from_email', 'test@example.com')
        if subject and message and from_email:
            try:
                send_mail(subject, message, from_email, ['admin@example.com'])
            except BadHeaderError:
                return HttpResponse('Invalid header found.')
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/contact/thanks/')
        else:
            # In reality we'd use a form class
            # to get proper validation errors.
            return HttpResponse('Make sure all fields are entered and valid.')
```

**Error:**

[image]

**Traceback:** 
I am adding a Traceback as well to clarify my question. Hope it helps

```
File "/home/jimtiaz/PycharmProjects/TestAoo/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py" in inner
  35.             response = get_response(request)

File "/home/jimtiaz/PycharmProjects/TestAoo/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  128.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "/home/jimtiaz/PycharmProjects/TestAoo/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  126.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "/home/jimtiaz/PycharmProjects/TestAoo/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py" in wrapper
  574.                 return self.admin_site.admin_view(view)(*args, **kwargs)

File "/home/jimtiaz/PycharmProjects/TestAoo/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  142.                     response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/home/jimtiaz/PycharmProjects/TestAoo/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/decorators/cache.py" in _wrapped_view_func
  44.         response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/home/jimtiaz/PycharmProjects/TestAoo/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/sites.py" in inner
  223.             return view(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/home/jimtiaz/PycharmProjects/TestAoo/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapper
  62.             return bound_func(*args, **kwargs)

File "/home/jimtiaz/PycharmProjects/TestAoo/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  142.                     response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/home/jimtiaz/PycharmProjects/TestAoo/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in bound_func
  58.                 return func.__get__(self, type(self))(*args2, **kwargs2)

File "/home/jimtiaz/PycharmProjects/TestAoo/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py" in changelist_view
  1596.                 response = self.response_action(request, queryset=cl.get_queryset(request))

File "/home/jimtiaz/PycharmProjects/TestAoo/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py" in response_action
  1330.             response = func(self, request, queryset)

Exception Type: TypeError at /admin/home/something
Exception Value: send_email() takes 1 positional argument but 3 were given
```

Comment: What is calling `send_email`? It's clear that the function signature expects one argument, what isn't clear is what is calling it with three arguments.

Comment: @JaredGoguen , let me check the trace in detail. Will get back to you

Comment: @JaredGoguen , i have added a Traceback in my question. Would that help you ?

Comment: Show your `urls.py` in which you hooked up this function to a URL.

Comment: @ThijsvanDien I did not assign any URL to this function. I added the action in admin page like this "                                   actions = [edit_selected_employee, send_mail]". Which gets called when i select send_mail and press 'Go' button

Comment: I like how the URL is censored in the image, but not right below it (Request URL: ...) or in the text traceback.

Comment: @NickT lol done now. Missed those

Comment: @Junaid they're in the history. Not sure why you're even bothering; the only thing worthwhile would be a domain name or public IP.

Comment: @NickT anyway i hope i can get this issue resolved today.

Comment: Is there a reason you're shadowing the `send_mail` name? You're going to try to call yourself. There's a deleted answer that I'm not sure why it's invalid as you could easily end up with a similar, but subtly different error once you fix the name problem.

Comment: The part that it's an admin action rather than a regular view is rather important.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you pointed out in your comment, this code is used for an admin action. However, in the [Writing action functions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/admin/actions/#writing-action-functions) section of the documentation, it's pointed out that such function should take three arguments. The given example:

```
def make_published(modeladmin, request, queryset):
    queryset.update(status='p')
```

Your function takes just one argument, but gets called with three, hence the error.

Change your function definition to:

```
def send_email(modeladmin, request, queryset):
```

Comment: Then it will crash with a `RecursionError`

Comment: @NickT How so? The name of his function is very similar but not equal to the imported function.

Comment: Ah, missed the e. The comments on the deleted answer didn't allude to that at all

Comment: @ThijsvanDien Worked Perfectly. Now I am getting this error which is related to sending email. ConnectionRefusedError.. The location is /usr/lib/python3.6/socket.py in create_connection

Comment: @ThijsvanDien I think i missed the SMTP settings in settings.py file, that's why connection refused

Comment: @Junaid Exactly. Seems like you haven't correctly configured Django for sending email. It needs a working SMTP.